Find all OpenStreetMap address points in a given area
How can I find ALL OpenStreetMap address points in a given area?
Let's say around Manila, Philippines.
OK, in https://overpass-turbo.eu/ I zoom into Manila. Then I enter addr:housenumber into the Wizard and press Run and... no results.

Use addr:housenumber=*.
By the way, you had better zoom in to a rather small area first, because the results will be, er, rather numerous.
